# Maintain whitespace when displaying text from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm putting up a table that displays values from a table. One of the fields comes from a textarea input.

If I use this method then whitespace is maintained:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.goalDescr, new { cols="90", rows="3", @readonly = "true"})
```

--example:

hey

there

--end example

However, I don't like that view so much as it still looks like a form field. I tried to use displayfor but the white space is removed and all text is one one line.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.goalDescr)
```

--example:

hey there

--end example

Is there a way to display text in my view in, outside of a form element, and maintain white space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

wrap your DB content into a [pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

```
<pre>
 All whitespaces      and linebreaks
are preserved

</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you sir - I knew it had to simple!

Comment: Also, if you don't like the auto-formatting `<pre>` does and want to keep your inherited styling simply use a `<span>` or `<div>` with the `style="whitespace:pre-wrap;"` attribute. I find this to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: quick correction for above comment. `style="white-space:pre-wrap;"`

Comment: @Johannes solution is best.

Comment: maybe @johannes should post its suggestion as an answer?

Comment: I added it as an answer as per request.

Answer (score 9):

As [Steve B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353542/573634) says, you can use `<pre>` to maintain whitespace.

If however you don't like the auto-formatting `<pre>` does and want to keep your inherited styling simply use a `<span>` or `<div>` with the `style="white-space:pre-wrap;"` attribute. I find this to be a more elegant solution.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tXHH8/1/)

Comment: I have to admit that you made me discover this css rule when you commented my answer. I use more often your solution than mine, since I know it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom helper which will replace new lines (`\r\n`) with `<br/>` tags.

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString FormatValue(this HtmlHelper html, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        value = string.Join(
            "<br/>", 
            value.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                 .Select(x => html.Encode(x))
        );
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(value);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.FormatValue(Model.goalDescr)
```

or wrap in a `<pre>` tag to preserve new lines:

```
<pre>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.goalDescr)
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin - I think I'll try the approach with <pre></pre> first. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `DisplayFor`, my guess is that it's rendering `input type="text"` instead of `textarea` which is the reason why it's displaying it in one line.

You can decorate you model with `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string goalDescr { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm getting a textarea - but I appreciate your response